# How to add array values to another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, for-loop, foreach

I have two array of values and their keys...
**First array**

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [10] => A1
            [11] => A2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [12] => B1
            [13] => B2
        )

)
```

**Second array**

```
Array
(
  [1] => Z1
  [2] => Z2
)
```

I want to group these two array into a single array. I mean the array format should be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [1] => Z1
        [10] => A1
        [11] => A2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [2] => Z2
        [12] => B1
        [13] => B2
    )
 )
```

I tried with array_push but add the entire array in the [0] position or in the [2] position in the second array.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: PHP. Oops, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
$arrOne = array(
    0 => array(
        10 => 'A1',
        11 => 'A2'
    ),
    1 => array(
        12 => 'B1',
        13 => 'B2'
    )
);

$arrTwo = array(
    1 => 'Z1',
    2 => 'Z2'
);
$arrcountone = count($arrOne);
$arrcounttwo = count($arrTwo);
$i=0;
foreach ($arrOne as $key1 => $value1) {
    $i++;$k=0;
    foreach ($arrTwo as $key => $value) {
        $k++;
        if($i == $k){
            $arrOne[$key1][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

`var_dump($arrOne)` gives

```
 array
      0 => 
        array
          1 => string 'Z1' (length=2)
          10 => string 'A1' (length=2)
          11 => string 'A2' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array
          2 => string 'Z2' (length=2)
          12 => string 'B1' (length=2)
          13 => string 'B2' (length=2)
```

Comment: +1 I realized that my answer didn't preserve the array keys. You beat me to it.